# Error 500 with elasticsearch php 6 update

Tags: php, elasticsearch-6

I try to use Elasticsearh 6 update function with no result. 
When I try this update with kibana dev tool it works.

This is my simplified code :

```
    $params = [
        'index' => 'users',
        'type'  => 'doc',
        'id'    => 'ZaFyimUBkV2X87VLF-A3',
        'body'  => [
            'doc' => [
                'validationcode' => '112233'
            ]
        ]
    ];        
    $results = $this->esClient->update($params);
```

When I run this code, I get:

```
500 Internal Server error !!!
```

All the other functions (get, index, etc) are working.
My mapping for this index:

```
{
"template" : "users*",
"mappings" : {
    "doc" : {
        "properties" : {
            "email" : { "type": "keyword" },
            "firstname" : { "type": "text" },
            "lastname" : { "type": "text" },
            "pseudo" : { "type" : "completion" },
            "password": { "type": "keyword" },
            "validationcode" : { "type": "short" },
            "verified" : { "type": "boolean" },
            "picture" : { "type" : "text" },
            "role" : { "type": "keyword" },
            "origin": { "type" : "keyword" },
            "langId" : { "type": "keyword" },
            "birthdate": { "type" : "date" },
            "options" : { "type" : "keyword" },
            "favorites" : { "type": "keyword" },
            "friends" : { "type": "keyword" },
            "subscriptions" : { "type" : "keyword" },
            "created" : { "type" : "date" },
            "updated" : { "type" : "date" },
            "location" : { "type": "geo_point" }
         }
    }
   }  
}
```

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: Sorry ! I found by myself ... my validation code was out of range because it was mapped as a short ... there was not reliable information in the apache logs. Thanks @aynber for your reply and have a good day !